Uncertainity in position in 1D potential box
In a question of a usual 1D box for a particle between $-L/2$  to  $L/2$ i had to compute $\Delta x$ and $\Delta p$ for the particle. The solution used the formulas-
$$\Delta x = \sqrt{\langle x^2 \rangle - \langle x \rangle^2}$$
$$ \Delta p = \sqrt{\langle p^2 \rangle - \langle p \rangle^2} $$ Though it might makes sense for $\Delta p$ but i thought that $\Delta x$ is just the length of 1d box which was given as $L$, since particle can be found anywhere inside that region. But as solved in the solution using the above formula gave a different result which is $\Delta x< \frac{L}{2 \sqrt 3}$.
Why is $\Delta x$ not $L$?

If we consider this graph as a probability distribution

then i see even beyond the standard deviation region of graph there are still some portion left where probability of finding particle is not 0 then how $\Delta x $ is limited to some portion of graph?

You need to specify the state your are analyzing. 1D particle in a box specification is irrelevant. Are you supposed to be looking at a specific state that is an energy eigenstate of the 1D particle in a box?

Oops, I forgot to mention it coz i was too concentrated on thinking about how$ \Delta x$ is not equal to L. The particle is in ground state and its ground state wavefunction is also provided

Then why do you think the normal distribution is relevant at all here…?

The standard deviation has an exact mathematical definition. It sounds like your main hang up is that you have internalized it as the hard limits across which the wave function is nonzero, but that's not the definition of standard deviation
$\Delta x$ is the standard deviation of multiple measurements of similarly prepared states. In other words, $\Delta x$ (really $\Delta$"anything") is determined by the state, not the potential energy function. Furthermore, $\Delta x=\sqrt{\langle x^2\rangle-\langle x\rangle^2}$ just follows from the definitions of standard deviation and mean, so I'm not sure what you mean by saying it makes sense for momentum but not position.
Conceptually, the standard deviation tells us how "spread out" the probability distribution is. While a rough estimate for $\Delta x$ for a particle in a box could be the length of the box $L$, there isn't any reason it always has to be exactly this. You can still have a state that is sharply peaked in $x$ evolve within the 1D potential well.

"Conceptually, the standard deviation tells us how "spread out" the probability distribution is." To find how spread out a function is we can just directly see its boundaries, but i know you meant by "spread out" that if the fuction is more peaky or flat..but if there is probability of finding particle beyond that range, then why $\Delta x$ is limited to certain portion of graph only? I added a diagram in the question to ask better about what confuses me here.

@SHINU_MADE for a Gaussian packet for a free particle, your method would say the uncertainty in position is infinite, so the particle could be anywhere. We definitely have more information than just that

Ofcourse, its not the case as i am well aware. I'm not saying that i am right, i know to span $\Delta x$ to whole function is wrong, but it just doesn't make a sense to say that the uncertainity in position of particle is say +/- 5 when particle can also be found at x=8.

@SHINU_MADE No, it makes perfectly sense. If I say the average IQ is 100 with standard deviation 15, then that doesn't mean (a priori) that there are no people with IQ larger than 115. See e.g. the picture you added to your question. I'd suggest to re-read about what the standard deviation etc. means, and then come back to a proper treatment of it in quantum mechanics.

@SHINU_MADE The standard deviation has an exact mathematical definition. It sounds like your main hang up is that you have internalized it as the hard limits across which the wave function is nonzero, but that's not the definition of standard deviation
